# How do I find total number of links on a web page using selenium and java 11?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

```
package exsc;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class S1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          // Give me the count of Links on a page  

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\JARs\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) new ChromeDriver();
      String url= "http://qaclickacademy.com/practice.php";
      driver.get(url);
      System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("a")).size());
   }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver
>       at exsc.S1.main(S1.java:13)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>       ... 1 more

Comment: `WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) new ChromeDriver();`  - why are you casting your driver object here?  `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` should work fine.

Comment: Earlier it forced me to cast in order to compile successfully. Now the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor point, instead of using xpath it'll be good if you use tagName in this scenario to find all the links. Something like this:

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size();
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue found with JAR mappings to the current project. Instead of importing external JARs to classpath in Build Path, it got imported to Modulepath.

Rearranging JARs solved the issue.